# Xpath to sum duplicate elements

Tags: xslt, xpath, sum

I have requirement on to find the duplicate elements in the input xml and sum the quantity with single record as output.

Input xml is:

```
<Input>
    <A1>
        <NAME>A</NAME>
        <QTY>1</QTY>
    </A1>
    <A1>
        <NAME>A</NAME>
        <QTY>2</QTY>
    </A1>
    <A2>
        <NAME>B</NAME>
        <QTY>3</QTY>
    </A2>
    <A1>
        <NAME>A</NAME>
        <QTY>5</QTY>
    </A1>
    <A2>
        <NAME>b</NAME>
        <QTY>8</QTY>
    </A2>
</Input>
```

output should be as below:

```
<Input>
    <A1>
        <NAME>A</NAME>
        <QTY>8</QTY>
    </A1>
    <A2>
        <NAME>B</NAME>
        <QTY>11</QTY>
    </A2>
</Input>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to sum several nodes of type number you can use the XPath `sum()` function. This adds all your `QTY` nodes:

```
sum(//QTY)
```

If you just want to add the nodes that are below `A1` you can use:

```
sum(/Input/A1/QTY)
```

or

```
sum(//A1/QTY)
```

which will have the same result considering the source you provided.

You can select the first `A1` with the same name using

```
//A1[1]
```

So, to obtain the result you want you could match `A1[1]` in a template and call `sum(//A1/QTY)` or `sum(/Input/A1/QTY)` inside it to obtain the sum. Then you repeat the process with `A2`.

You can achieve this with two recursive templates:

The `sum` expression here obtains the value of the node `*` which may be `A1` or `A2`. The XPath expression compares its name `name(current())` with the `name()` of each child of Input (`/Input/*`), which will match either `A1` or `A2`, adding the amount in the `QTY` of each node.